# Saving a Uint8Array to a binary file

Tags: javascript, file-io, cross-browser, binary-data, typed-arrays

I am working on a web app that opens binary files and allows them to be edited.

This process is basically `ondrop -> dataTransfer.files[0] -> FileReader -> Uint8Array`

Essentially, I want to be able to save the modified file back as a binary file. Ideally as a file download with a specified file name.

There doesn't seem to be any standard method of doing this, and that sucks, because everything up to that point is well supported.

I am currently converting the array to a string using `String.fromCharCode()`, base64 encoding that, and using a data uri in a hyperlink like `data:application/octet-stream;base64,..`, along with the `download` attribute to specify filename.

It seems to work, but it's quite hacky and I think converting the raw bytes to a string might introduce encoding issues depending on the byte values. I don't want the data to become corrupt or break the string.

Barring that, is there a better/proper method for getting an array of bytes as a binary file to the user?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

These are utilities that I use to download files cross-browser. The nifty thing about this is that you can actually set the `download` property of a link to the name you want your filename to be.

FYI the mimeType for binary is `application/octet-stream`

```
var downloadBlob, downloadURL;

downloadBlob = function(data, fileName, mimeType) {
  var blob, url;
  blob = new Blob([data], {
    type: mimeType
  });
  url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  downloadURL(url, fileName);
  setTimeout(function() {
    return window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }, 1000);
};

downloadURL = function(data, fileName) {
  var a;
  a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = data;
  a.download = fileName;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.style = 'display: none';
  a.click();
  a.remove();
};
```

Usage:

```
downloadBlob(myBinaryBlob, 'some-file.bin', 'application/octet-stream');
```

Comment: This confuses me, the parameters in downloadURL are different to the parameters used to call it.

Comment: the example uses `downloadBlob` (the first function) that then calls `downloadURL` so the args reflect the first function not the 2nd one

Comment: You are calling `downloadURL(url, filename, mimeType)` from within `downloadBlob` but the function is `downloadURL(data, filename)`, so unless there is same magic happening that I don't understand, it's not matching. I think it's a case of just removing the `mimeType` but when first trying to understand it it's still confusing.

Comment: [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) is a pretty solid library for handling file downloads across multiple browsers. Under the hood it does essentially the same thing as your code but adjusts for different browsers that don't support the method.

Comment: this is saving a list of integers separated by commas...

Comment: Awesome! I was able to simply paste this code into the browser console while stopped at a breakpoint and download a UInt8Array to a file in Safari on Mac.

Answer (score 17):

(shorter) ES6 version of the top answer:

```js
const downloadURL = (data, fileName) => {
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  a.href = data
  a.download = fileName
  document.body.appendChild(a)
  a.style.display = 'none'
  a.click()
  a.remove()
}

const downloadBlob = (data, fileName, mimeType) => {

  const blob = new Blob([data], {
    type: mimeType
  })

  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)

  downloadURL(url, fileName)

  setTimeout(() => window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url), 1000)
}
```

Comment: Even shorter if data is always Blob :) `DL=(d,f)=>{let a=document.createElement("a"),u=URL.createObjectURL(d);a.download=f,a.href=u,a.click(),setTimeout(()=>URL.revokeObjectURL(u))}`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from this [link](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/javascript-save-typed-array-as-blob-and-read-back-in-as-binary-data) :

"Solution 2:
As per Mozilla.
Here is an example on how to create a URL to a typed array using a blob. The source of this example is from Mozilla Developer Network's API documentation for Blob."

```
var blob = new Blob([typedArray.buffer], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
```

It works in Edge and Chrome.